# Is dynamic topic remapping implemented in ROS2 Dashing?

Tags: ros, ros2, remapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the documentation I have seen at the links below

https://design.ros2.org/articles/static_remapping.html (bottom of page)

https://www.osrfoundation.org/wordpress2/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/ROSCON-2014-Why-you-want-to-use-ROS-2.pdf (slides 23 -24)

It seems ros2 nodes are supposed to support dynamic remapping of their topics at runtime. However, I do not see any documentation on this. I feel this feature is useful during development and debugging, so I would like to see it implemented.

Is this feature implemented in Dashing? If not, is it still on the roadmap?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343568/is-dynamic-topic-remapping-implemented-in-ros2-dashing?/) by [msmcconnell](https://answers.ros.org/users/30781/msmcconnell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 268 on 2020-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, it is not yet implemented and still on the roadmap: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Roadmap/#new-features

Atm there is no plan for anybody to work on this in the foreseeable future.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fmrico](https://answers.ros.org/users/13346/fmrico/) on 2023-05-23**:
Do you know if it is still in the roadmap or if it has been implemented?